# Group by date using a unix timestamp column

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

It works, but can it be simplified?

`timeaccess` is updated with php `time()` - which is a unix timestamp.

```
select to_date(to_char(to_timestamp(timeaccess),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
from user_login;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(timeaccess)::date
FROM   user_login
```

You can cast the resulting timestamp to date, `::` being the casting operator.